# Checking existence of Pivot table with it's name using formula

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

I have a report that I'm building that contains pivot tables, the names of which (i.e. PivotTable1) are referenced explicitly in the VBA code.

I wanted to include a formula-based check in the workbook itself that the pivot table existed (essentially checking that a user hadn't changed the name of the table or deleted it completely).

I use the following work-around to check that tables exist using their name:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("NameOfTable"),1,1))))
```

Can anyone suggest anything similar for pivots using native Excel functions?

Answer (score 0):

Is the creation of a VBA user defined function an option? In this case I'd suggest

```
Public Function ExistPivot(PTName As String) As Boolean
Dim WS As Worksheet, PT As PivotTable

    ExistPivot = False
    For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each PT In WS.PivotTables
            If PT.Name = PTName Then
                ExistPivot = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next PT
    Next WS
End Function
```

and use it in the worksheet as `=ExistPivot("xxx")`, result will be either TRUE or FALSE

Comment: I was hoping to do it with only native functions as the VBA knowledge within my team isn't great. From scouring the internet there doesn't seem to be any trick that does it though so a UDF might be the way forward.

Comment: the closest you might get is to use a `=GETPIVOTDATA()` function (http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/getpivotdata-function-HP010342556.aspx) which takes the name of the pivot table as the 2nd argument, but you also must know at least one data field - meaning you can use this as long as the design of the pivot table is always the same.